# Invite team member functionality in MERN website

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am building a website using mern stack where every user who signs up gets their own subdomain according to the username they entered.

What I have done so far:

1. Users can create an account and get their subdomain according to the username they entered while signing up.
2. Owner of the organization can send invites to the team members using email by filling out a simple form where they need to enter the email of the team member.

Now, I would like to know how I can add the team member to the organisation's workspace so they have full access to the workspace. Basically, I don't know what to do after sending an invite.

Please give me some insights on how this can be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an array element in the your model so that contains group_ids of groups joined.
2. Create a middle-ware function that checks if the user can perform operations in there. If not, throw error.
3. When the invite is sent, the array element that I talked about should be updated to [...array, group_id selected].

I am a junior developer so might go wrong but I hope this helps.